# Exporting the results of an Anylogic experiment

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have built my model and run the experiment. I cannot seem to find where the data is stored.

I now need to conduct several runs and compare the results, I am using normally distributed repair times so the results should vary between runs without modifying parameters.

How can I keep the results of each run and then present them all in the same data set?

Answer (score 3):

There are two main options for getting data out of your simulation

1. Using the internal AnyLogic database
2. Using external files like Excel or txt

**Step 1: Setup your objects**

1. Internal Database

Create an empty table with the columns you require

[image]

2. External object

Setup either an Excel or text file using the objects provided by AnyLogic in the Connectivity palette

[image]

**Step 2: Saving your data**

For both cases you need to write your data to the object of your choosing, either as the data gets generated or at the end of the simulation model

1. using Internal DB

The best option is to write data using the following command

```
insertInto(table_name)
    .columns(column_name)
    .values(value);
```

This will just insert a new line into a database table that you created, you can save multiple values to multiple columns by adding comma-separated entries into the parameters for columns and values.

e.g

```
insertInto(temeprature_output_table)
    .columns(scenario_name, time, temperature)
    .values("sceanrio1", 10,5, 102);
```

2. External files

2.1) Using Excel

`filename.setCellValue(value, sheetName, row, column);`

or even better you can write out an entire dataset

`excelFile.writeDataSet(dataset, sheetName, row, column);`

2.2) Using a text file

`fileName.println("value" + "\t" + " value 2");`

You can use whatever separator you want `"\t"` for tab separated or `","` for comma and so on

**Step 3: Finish and export data**

1. Internal Database
   At the end of a simulation run, you can simply export the data
   [image]

See help here https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/export-excel.html#exporting-data-to-ms-excel-workbook

P.S. It is possible to automate this with some effort

2. External file

On Excel you need to call `.writeFile()` to finish.
On both objects, you need to call `.close()` for them to be closed and saved to memory.

FYI
Excel has the option to save on termination.

[image]

Read more on using Excel here - https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/excel-file.html#writing-to-excel-file

And on text file here
https://anylogic.help/anylogic/connectivity/text-file.html#replicated

There is also an example model

[image]